# how to exclude project class files when using maven assembly plugin?

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using maven assembly plugin to package all my dependencies in a zip inside lib folder.
I am also adding the project artifact using

```xml
<useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
```

The only problem is that in the final zip I am also seeing the project class files. I want to exclude them since lib already contains the artifact, but after trying various options, no success so far.

here is my assembly.xml

```xml
<assembly>
  <id>binary</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

The classes of your project appear in your assembly because your are including them in your assembly with this :

```xml
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

So if you don't want your project's classes in your assembly then you have to remove this part from your assembly descriptor.

As a reminder, the variable `${project.build.outputDirectory}` is by default the folder `target/classes`.